# Using curl to load data from webservice bt getting error

Tags: php, web-services, curl

```
$ch = curl_init();
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,"webservcieLink");
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, "select * from table_name");
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
 $server_output = curl_exec($ch);
 $xml = new SimpleXMLElement($server_output);
 $xml = json_decode($xml, true);
curl_close ($ch);
```

**Error I am getting is :**
Warning: SimpleXMLElement::__construct(): Entity: line 28: parser error : AttValue: " or ' expected

Comment: Error is on line 7 which is 
$xml = new SimpleXMLElement($server_output);

Comment: Can you echo the output of `$server_output` and show us what you get? This will help to arrive at a solution. So, after `$server_output = curl_exec($ch);` add the following: `die($server_output);`

Comment: The question is not about curl.  See the $server_output is something expected for SimpleXMLElement  ```$xml = new SimpleXMLElement```.  Also, you can't decode xml with json, no matter if it is xml string or a dom element, so this does not make sense ```$xml = json_decode($xml, true);```